# Django form NEVER posts

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

This is rather weird. I've been using Django forms for a long time and can't figure this out.

I have a small form with 1 field for "Quantity". Whenever I submit the form nothing happens and it NEVER get's into my condition to check if the request method is a POST. I have put a pdb in the code as well and it never reaches. I am not sure why. Here is the code.

### views.py

```
def show_product(request, product_slug, template_name='catalog/product.html'):
    product_cache_key = request.path
    product = cache.get(product_cache_key)
    if not product:
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=product_slug)
        cache.set(product_cache_key, product, settings.CACHE_TIMEOUT)
    categories = product.categories.filter(is_active=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace() # it NEVER hit's this
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        form = ProductAddToCartForm(request, postdata)
        if form.is_valid():
            cart.add_to_cart(request)
            if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                request.session.delete_test_cookie()
            url = urlresolvers.reverse('show_cart')
            return redirect(url)
    else:
        form = ProductAddToCartForm(request=request)
    form.fields['product_slug'].widget.attrs['value'] = product_slug
    request.session.set_test_cookie()
    context = RequestContext(request, locals())
    return render_to_response(template_name, context)
```

### forms.py

```
class ProductAddToCartForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input-quantity', 'placeholder': 'Qty'}), error_messages={'invalid': 'Please enter a valid quantity.'}, min_value=1)
    product_slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        super(ProductAddToCartForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        if self.request:
            if not self.request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                raise forms.ValidationError("Sorry, please enable your cookies.")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

### template

```
    <form method="post" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.quantity.errors }}
        {{ form.quantity }}
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-danger" />
        {{ form.product_slug }}
    </form>
```

When I click "Add to Cart" the URL goes from `http://localhost:8000/product/arm-glove/` to this one `http://localhost:8000/product/arm-glove/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=RFG0F1Lg0Eu3GcDhtYwPPCpy9Oct5zCX&quantity=2&submit=Add+to+Cart&product_slug=arm-glove`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does the request make it to the view function? Does it always to GETs? What do the dev tools say the form is doing?

Comment: It makes it to the function, the form renders so this `form = ProductAddToCartForm(request=request)` is working

Comment: Ok, so if you log the request.method it == 'GET'? And what do the dev tools say the form is sending on the client side?

Comment: it will definitely be a GET since the form is rendering and not POSTing, I tried that and pdb drops into the (pdb) console as suspected.... I just found something... an unclosed form tag well above that is only a GET for searches.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was an unclosed  tag used for the search which is a GET request so the form's POST was never being seen.